# apache failing to boot

Tags: apache, system-calls, strace

I successfully installed apache on my machine,but when I try to run it throws core dump.

I ran it again using strace,it throws core dump at `write` system call.

Below is the extract from output of stace. What can I infer from this error ?

```
write(2, "/tools/abc/local/bin/apachectl: line 79: 14372 Segmentation fault      (core dump"..., 120/tools/abc/local/bin/apachectl: line 79: 14372 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $HTTPD -k $ARGV
) = 120
```

**EDIT**
Output of `strace -s 100 httpd -k start`

```
execve("/tools/abc/local/bin/httpd", ["httpd", "-k", "start"], [/* 38 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xe7e000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffa0aece000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffa0aecd000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffa0aecc000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffa0aecd680) = 0
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Memory fault(coredump)
```

Comment: how did you install `apache`? by compiling source code or by installing packages.

Comment: By compiling from source.

Comment: what version? have you checked if your version is compatible with your current system configuration , existing packages? or did you simply download the source and compile and install?

Comment: I have another user on same machine where it runs fine,installed using the same source code.

Server version: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 20 2013 18:36:16

Comment: is that other user `root`? if not what are the main differences between the two users? we can probably narrow the problem if we find out those differences

Comment: Both the users are non-root.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48658/discussion-between-anurupr-and-g4ur4v)

Comment: refer to this link http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197
 try to debug the core dump and see what the error is. get back to us if you need more help